# Oracle Apex, Clear page when reloading in browser

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a question, how can I clear all filters, tables and diagrams when the page gets reloaded in the browser?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Try to

- create a "Page load" dynamic action
- whose action is "Clear"
- and affected element's type is "Triggering element"

Comment: Thanks, I now created a Button with a dynamic action, that refreshes the items, that are my filters. It's one step more, but only one click, so no problem.